# Sending multiple pings with Python

Tags: python

How can I ping `192.168.0.1` - `192.168.0.254` all at once? Trying to make the script run faster as it takes several minutes to finish.

```
import os
import subprocess


ip = raw_input("IP Address? ")
print "Scanning IP Address: " + ip

subnet = ip.split(".")

FNULL = open(os.devnull, 'w')

for x in range(1, 255):
    ip2 = subnet[0]+"."+ subnet[1] +"."+ subnet[2] +"."+ str(x)
    response=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip2], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).wait()
if response == 0:
    print ip2, 'is up!'
else:
    print ip2, 'is down!'
```

Comment: Look into `multiprocessing` module's `Pool`.

Comment: @jacob isn't multiprocessing's Pool for when you want to start and coordinate a bunch of python processes? The code is already starting processes (which is what Popen does), so you'd only be starting processes to start processes, which would become interesting very fast.

Comment: @Pyonsuke Yeah; but he was calling `wait` on the process each time. Using `multiprocessing` you could start a process for each `subprocess.Popen` and each one can have it's own `wait`. Not saying it's optimal but it was the first thing that came to mind.

Comment: Far from optimal, you would be starting 256 instances of Python and 255 instances of ping at the same time for a total of 511 processes.. I'm somewhat curious if a system could even handle that properly. Though you might be thinking of the threading module instead, which creates "threads" within the same process (doesn't utilise multiple cores, for example, but since this is IO bound it doesn't have to) However even that is still kind of overkill since ultimately, Popen is already starting a process, and therefore already effectively starting "threads" which you can both .poll() and .wait() on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the method you use to get a response:

```
response=subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip2], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).wait()
```

most importantly, the `.wait()` at the end means your program will wait until the process finishes.

You can start 255 processes at once (though you might want to start smaller chunks for the case of sanity) by putting the result of Popen (and not wait) into a list:

```
processes = []
for ip8 in range(1, 255):
    ip32 = subnet[0]+"."+ subnet[1] +"."+ subnet[2] +"."+ str(ip8)
    process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip32], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    processes.append(process)
```

You can then go through each and every process and wait until they finish:

```
for process, ip8 in zip(processes, range(1, 255)):
    ip32 = subnet[0]+"."+ subnet[1] +"."+ subnet[2] +"."+ str(ip8)
    response = process.wait()
    if response == 0:
        print("%s is up!" % (ip32))
    else:
        print("%s is down!" % (ip32))
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of waiting for each process to finish in your loop you can start all the processes at once and save them in a list:

```
processes = []

for x in range(1, 255):
    ip2 = subnet[0]+"."+ subnet[1] +"."+ subnet[2] +"."+ str(x)
    process = subprocess.Popen(["ping", "-c", "1", "-n", "-W", "2", ip2], stdout=FNULL, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    processes.append((ip2, process))
```

Then you can then wait for each process to finish and print the results:

```
for ip2, process in processes:
    response = process.wait()
    if response == 0:
        print ip2, 'is up!'
    else:
        print ip2, 'is down!'
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you could ping them all with one ping to the subnet broadcast address. So if your subnet is `255.255.255.0` (also known as `/24`) then just ping `192.168.0.255` and *normally* everyone will ping back.